# Apollo Stomp ActiveMQ Creates Invalid Temporary Destination Names

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, stomp, apollo

Using C# framework 4.0 where the broker is running as a service on Windows 7 32bit I am seeing the following errors on both the stable and development versions.

```
2012-09-09 20:25:03,524 | WARN  | Internal Server Error: org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.path.PathParser$PathException: Invalid destination: 'ID\cEros201-30171-634828191032886763-1\c0\c1', it does not match regex: [ a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\%\~\:]+ | org.apache.activemq.apollo.stomp.StompProtocolHandler | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-2
2012-09-09 20:25:03,542 | WARN  | Internal Server Error: org.apache.activemq.apollo.util.path.PathParser$PathException: Invalid destination: 'ID\cEros201-30171-634828191032886763-1\c0\c1', it does not match regex: [ a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\%\~\:]+ | org.apache.activemq.apollo.stomp.StompProtocolHandler | hawtdispatch-DEFAULT-3
```

The end result of this is I am unable to use temporary queues as the call blocks on the client and the session times out before I can respond to the exception.

```
Versions 
    Client dlls Stomp 1.5.2 NMS 1.5.0 
    Broker server apache-apollo-1.4 and apache-apollo-99-trunk-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: How are you specifying the queue name? This seems like some parsing issue or related to encoding.

Comment: Have you tried using the Apache.NMS.Stomp v1.5.3 release

Comment: The .net api provided hides the specifying of names for temporary destinations. I assume a bug in the client api layer or a config mismatch with the broker (at least out of the box).

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, instead of using Apache.NMS.Stomp switch to Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.  Apache Apollo support both the STOMP and ActiveMQ protocols on the 61613 port.

Comment: Thanks for such a fast reply. We are using the broker intermediary to support Html5 and older scripting clients so Stomp over ws is our primary need. My current workaround is to use named queues for client sessions and manually delete them in a cleanup service at a later time. Not ideal though.